# How to ensure kubernetes cronjob does not restart on failure

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cronjob that sends out emails to customers.  It occasionally fails for various reasons.  I *do not want* it to restart, but it still does.

I am running Kubernetes on GKE.  To get it to stop, I have to delete the CronJob and then kill all the pods it creates manually.

This is bad, for obvious reasons.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-06-21T14:48:46Z
  name: dailytasks
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "20390223"
  selfLink: [redacted]
  uid: [redacted]
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
          - command:
            - kubernetes/daily_tasks.sh
            env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: status.hostIP
            envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: my-secrets
            image: [redacted]
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: dailytasks
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Never
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: 0 14 * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: true
status:
  active:
  - apiVersion: batch
    kind: Job
    name: dailytasks-1533218400
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "20383182"
    uid: [redacted]
  lastScheduleTime: 2018-08-02T14:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It turns out that you have to set a `backoffLimit: 0` in combination with `restartPolicy: Never` in combination with `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid`.

**backoffLimit** means the number of times it will retry before it is considered failed.    The default is 6.

**concurrencyPolicy** set to `Forbid` means it will run 0 or 1 times, but not more.

**restartPolicy** set to `Never` means it won't restart on failure.

You need to do all 3 of these things, or your cronjob may run more than once.

```
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      [ADD THIS -->]backoffLimit: 0
      template: 
      ... MORE STUFF ...
```

Comment: Minor comment, the `backoffLimit` is the number of *retries*, not *tries*: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#jobspec-v1-batch

Comment: I have the exact same use-case but this does not work for me :(
Can you think of why? What kube version are you using?

Comment: Related question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355744/how-do-i-make-sure-my-cronjob-job-does-not-retry-on-failure

Comment: Make sure that you add the tags in the correct place, else it will not work. I did the mistake initially and after correcting it, it worked. thanks

Comment: Where should the restartPolicy go, it's not part of this example?

Comment: The `concurrencyPolicy` has nothing to do with the number of retries or failures. It has to do whether a long-running job that goes past its next interval will cause the other job to start or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my yaml. In this yaml kubernetes cronjob does not restart on failure. You need: "backoffLimit: 0", "concurrencyPolicy: Forbid", "failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1", "restartPolicy: Never"

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "0 4 * * *"
  timeZone: "Europe/Moscow"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-app
            image: docker-registry:1234/my-app:v1
            imagePullPolicy: Always
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: reg-cred-secret              
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score -4):

The kubernetes cronjob resources has a field, [`suspend`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/cronjob/cronjob_controller.go#L248-L251) in its spec.

You can't do it by default, but if you want to ensure it doesn't run, you could update the script that sends emails and have it patch the cronjob resource to add `suspend: true` if it fails

Something like this

```
kubectl patch cronjob <name> -p '{"spec": { "suspend": true }}'
```