# How do I make sure my cronjob job does NOT retry on failure?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cucumber-jvm, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a Kubernetes Cronjob that runs on GKE and runs Cucumber JVM tests. In case a Step fails due to assertion failure, some resource being unavailable, etc., Cucumber rightly throws an exception which leads the Cronjob job to fail and the Kubernetes pod's status changes to `ERROR`. This leads to creation of a new pod that tries to run the same Cucumber tests again, which fails again and retries again.

I don't want any of these retries to happen. If a Cronjob job fails, I want it to remain in the failed status and not retry at all. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657105/how-to-ensure-kubernetes-cronjob-does-not-restart-on-failure), I have already tried setting `backoffLimit: 0` in combination with `restartPolicy: Never` in combination with `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid`, but it still retries by creating new pods and running the tests again.

What am I missing? Here's my kube manifest for the Cronjob:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: quality-apatha
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: quality-apatha
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: quality-apatha
              image: FOO-IMAGE-PATH
              imagePullPolicy: "Always"
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 500m
                  memory: 512Mi
              env:
                - name: FOO
                  value: BAR
              volumeMounts:
                - name: FOO
                  mountPath: BAR
              args:
                - java
                - -cp
                - qe_java.job.jar:qe_java-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
                - org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
                - com.liveramp.qe_java.RunCucumberTest
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
            - name: FOO
              secret:
                secretName: BAR
```

Is there any other Kubernetes `Kind` I can use to stop the retrying?

Thank you!

Comment: The yaml looks fine. I assume you are using that schedule for testing? How often is the new pod being created?

Comment: I was misinterpreting legit schedule with pod retries :-|

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To make things as simple as possible I tested it using [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#example) example from the official kubernetes documentation, applying to it minor modifications to illustrate what really happens in different scenarios.

I can confirm that when `backoffLimit` is set to `0` and `restartPolicy` to `Never` **everything works exactly as expected and there are no retries**. Note that every single run of your `Job` which in your example is scheduled to run **at intervals of 60 seconds** (`schedule: "*/1 * * * *"`) **IS NOT considerd a retry**.

Let's take a closer look at the following example (base `yaml` avialable [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#example)):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - non-existing-command
          restartPolicy: Never
```

It spawns new cron job `every 60 seconds` according to the `schedule`, no matter if it fails or runs successfully. In this particular example it is configured to fail as we are trying to run `non-existing-command`.

You can check what's happening by running:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
hello-1587558720-pgqq9   0/1     Error               0          61s
hello-1587558780-gpzxl   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1s
```

As you can see there are **no retries**. Although the first `Pod` failed, the new one is spawned exactly 60 seconds later according to our specification. I'd like to emphasize it again. **This is not a retry.**

On the other hand when we modify the above example and set `backoffLimit: 3`, we can observe the **retries**. As you can see, now new `Pods` are created **much more often than every 60 seconds**. **This are retries.**

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
hello-1587565260-7db6j   0/1     Error    0          106s
hello-1587565260-tcqhv   0/1     Error    0          104s
hello-1587565260-vnbcl   0/1     Error    0          94s
hello-1587565320-7nc6z   0/1     Error    0          44s
hello-1587565320-l4p8r   0/1     Error    0          14s
hello-1587565320-mjnb6   0/1     Error    0          46s
hello-1587565320-wqbm2   0/1     Error    0          34s
```

What we can see above are **3 retries** (`Pod` creation attempts), related with `hello-1587565260` **job** and **4 retries** (including the orignal **1st try** not counted in `backoffLimit: 3`) related with `hello-1587565320` **job**.

As you can see the **jobs** themselves are still run according to the schedule, **at 60 second intervals**:

```
kubectl get jobs
NAME               COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
hello-1587565260   0/1           2m12s      2m12s
hello-1587565320   0/1           72s        72s
hello-1587565380   0/1           11s        11s
```

However due to our `backoffLimit` set this time to `3`, every time the `Pod` responsible for running the job fails, **3 additional retries occur**.

I hope this helped to dispel any possible confusions about running `cronJobs` in **kubernetes**.

If you are rather interested in running something just once, not at regular intervals, take a look at simple [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#running-an-example-job) instead of `CronJob`.

Also consider changing your [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) configuration if you still want to run this particular job on regular basis but let's say once in 24 h, not every minute.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I was misinterpreting legit schedule with pod retries :-|